# ColdFusion 7 Client Calling Asp.NET / WCF Service

Tags: wcf, coldfusion

ColdFusion 7.0 Client will be passing form data to a asp.net web handler , the handler must parse the form data as present in the Request.context  all this currently being done I now need to incorporate security between the  sender and receiver. The messages must be encrypted and also both the client and the service must mutually authenticate one another. The ColdFusion Client is sending large volumes of data around 150 fields are being passed. How to incorporate security into this mix. Because of client’s ColdFusion 7 my little research did not result in any way to use WCF (more support is provided in ColdFusion 9) maybe some has done this can let me know how to make a WCF call from ColdFusion 7.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty example, it's not different than a web service if the WCF is setup correctly:

```
<cfscript>
  wcf = CreateObject("webservice","http://ws.spreety.com/TvOnline2009.svc?wsdl");
  variables.TalkShowImgHtml = wcf.GetGenreTalkShowImg("test@spreety.com");
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>#variables.TalkShowImgHtml#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion supports web services. You can therefore have a ColdFusion web service client.

On the server side you can have a WCF service, that uses basicHttpBinding.

For encryption you can use https. The SSL certificate will also authenticate the server.

You can then use certificates on the client side to authenticate the client. (you could also use username and password over SSL.)

Comment: Thanks Shiraz can you point me to an example of where this is done and also from where I can download cold fusion 7